# Preserve formatting when referencing cells across sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formatting

Is there a way to show the formatting of the referenced cells from another sheet in Google Sheets?

For example I have a sheet named `balance` with `A1` having a comment and a blue background. When I reference this cell in another sheet within the same document (called `rent`) - ie `=balance! A1` then only the value of the cell shows up - not the comment or the background color.

It would also be useful to know if this can be done with the `ImportRange()` function so as to have this functionality available when referencing other spreadsheet documents.

Comment: These things can only be achieved by using google apps script. One can write a script, that can be used as a function within your spreadsheet, that collects all these data and adds it to the ative cell. Is this what you want?

Comment: This is the best answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/50623/29140

Comment: theirs is a duplicate of mine. check out the dates. but thanks for the link! :)

Comment: I chose yours, because the other one has an answer....