# Is it possible to import cell data AND cell format from one Google sheet to another?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I'm trying to import data "and" **formatting** from one sheet to another. I'm using `=importrange("docID", "sheetName!A1:A30")` to get the data, but it doesn't get the format.

Suggestions?

Comment: This can only be done with an Apps Script, unfortunately (and it can't be a custom function, since they can't access other spreadsheets). See [Cell reference with colour formatting](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/50409)